# Overriding groovy invokeMethod causes compile error in java

Tags: java, groovy

Scenario:
We have some java builder which we use to create objects for integration tests. A builder creates a valid domain object with default values. If different values are wanted they can be changed.

```
Foo fooWithDefaultValue = new FooBuilder().build()
Foo fooWithChangedValue = new FooBuilder().withValue("someValue").build()
```

We want to build a new type of builder which creates an object and persists it.

```
Foo fooInDB = new FooDatabaseBuilder().withValue("dbValue").persist()
```

Since the withValue methods will be same like in our old builders we want to reuse the old builder and not copy the code into the new one plus a persist method.

Our first try was groovy to use @Delegate to delegate from FooDbBuilder to FooBuilder.

```
class FooDatabaseBuilder {
    @Delegate
    private FooBuilder = new FooBuilder();

    public void persist(){
      // persist code here
   }
}
```

That worked for the delegate part but the return value of FooDatabaseBuilder.withValue() was FooBuilder which destroys the fluid approach. So we changed the invokeMethod in the Metaclass of FooDatabaseBuilder to return FooDatabaseBuilder. If we use those builders in groovy everything works, but in java we have a compile error since java does not see the invokeMethod changes.

How can i build such a dbBuilder, which can be used like a builder with the additional method to persist the created object?

Comment: What compiler error do you get?

Comment: It says FooBuilder has no method persist when i call new FooDatabaseBuilder().withValue("dbValue").persist()